# chronometer position not static

Tags: android, textview, chronometer

When the timer start to tick, the 'text' sometime is moving.. what u think is the cause? I make the chronometer inside a relative layout with match parent filled..

is there any other setting I miss out? I also set gravity : center of the chronometer

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" >

    <Chronometer
        android:id="@+id/stopwatch"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Chronometer"
        android:textSize="110dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `android:gravity="center_horizontal"` is the problem. It is re-aligning the text centered horizontally each time the text changes from an incremental tick. If you remove your center alignments in your Chronometer then you won't have the issue as it should default to left alignment.

You may have to use margins to position the Chronometer where you need it to be within your layout instead. For example:

```
<Chronometer
        android:id="@+id/stopwatch"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:text="Chronometer"
        android:textSize="110dp" />
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" >

    <Chronometer
        android:id="@+id/stopwatch"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Chronometer"
        android:textSize="110sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: text size should be given in sp not in dp